# Ionic 2 application take too much to launch on android device each and everytime.?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I already try this command : `ionic build android --prod --release` but still same result. How can one reduce the launching time of an ionic 2 application?

Comment: What is 'too much'? What device are you testing on? Please eleborate more ..

Comment: android devices 7.1.2  Nougat, it takes too much time to loading when i press off button and on immediately login screen show.but it takes around 1-2 minutes sometimes.

Comment: You'll have to share some or your code in order to help you, this is very unuseful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the plugins, there must be a problem with some plugin that would give error and increase loading time.

Answer (score 0):

Add lazy loading in some components or upgrade ionic version3+ which brings angular 4